# Backbone Boilerplate grunt-bbb generated todomvc returns 404

Tags: javascript, web-applications, backbone.js, nodes, gruntjs

I am new to backbone Bloilerplate.I tried to follow this [guide](https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/grunt-bbb) and installed grunt-bb

and then did this:

```
mkdir todomvc
bbb int
```

Bloilerplate files successful.Then

```
bbb init:todomvc
```

To domvc files generated also.
Then ran the server as

```
bbb server
```

The server is now listening at localhost:8000

The problem is that my screen is blank and I get this 404 in localhost:8000/assets/css/h5bp.css. Otherwise other files like backbonejs are loaded.

The main problem is that there is nothing on the page(Empty page). Is there any issue with bbb that I should know? I am stuck, kindly help.Thank you.

Comment: not an answer to your problem but you could also try yeoman: http://yeoman.io/ - it also comes with backbone and bbb generators plus a bunch of other features..

Comment: Thanks for reply. Trying yeoman. I will let you know the outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that bbb's directory layout has evolved but the included todomvc example hasn't been updated yet.
You can now find HTML5 Boilerplate CSS in `vendor/h5bp/css` (normalize.css and main.css).

You may find that you've got two index.css files (in `assets/css/index.css` and `app/styles/index.css`).
In this case, keep the last one, move your `assets/css/todo.css` in `app/styles/` and reference it in `app/styles/index.css` : `@import "todo.css;"`. Finally, you'll need to update your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/styles/index.css">
```

Note that all the JS files haved moved to `/vendor` too.